# Custom circuit fabrication for modified arduino based IoT

Tags: arduino, iot

i am learning arduino and want to build a circuit specific to my need with bluetooth, small factor etc. I have created a design in eagal. Is it possible to get is printed with components. what is the beast place to do that.

Comment: This is probably the wrong place to ask, this has nothing to do with programming

Comment: where should i ask then?

Comment: you may look into super user.Hardware is dealt there.

Comment: Try the Arduino section of stack exchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are new to Arduino (and circuit design in general), I would suggest that you take a look at the tutorials offered by [Adafruit](https://learn.adafruit.com/using-the-adafruit-library-with-fritzing/updating-to-the-latest-version-of-the-library?view=all) and [Sparkfun](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/pcb-basics).

Both of those companies use [Fritzing](http://fritzing.org/home/) to create their circuit diagrams.  Fritzing is an easy to use layout software and they have their own [fabrication service](https://aisler.net/fritzing).  Their tools are easy to use and economical for low production runs.  Alternatively, [Seeed Studio](https://www.seeedstudio.com/fusion_pcb.html) offers a PCB fabrication and assembly service.

Generally, if you are in the prototyping stage it can be cost prohibitive to automate the PCB assembly process with a [pick and place machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMT_placement_equipment), so the assembly is done by hand.  You may find it cheaper to learn to solder or find a friend to assemble your board.

Comment: This is very helpful. Do they also put components on it.

Comment: Not in their basic service, but you can pay for components and stencils.  I updated the answer with a reference to Seeed Studio which does do assembly.  You'll need to compare prices yourself for your specific board layout.  Even if you have made a breadboard prototype of your circuit, there can be new issues that are discovered during the PCB fab process.  You may be able to save a lot of money if you do _not_ pay for an assembly service and do it yourself.  Be prepared to do multiple iterations of your PCB.

Answer (score 1):

Any pcb manufacturer will produce pcbs for you. it's all a matter of how much you are willing to pay, where you live, what quality you expect and how long you want to wait. You can get cheap PCBs from China if you are willing to wait several weeks and don't have to high expectations regarding quality.

Having a single PCB manufactured and populated will most likely cost you a few houndred dollars, depending on how many layers you have, how many components...
It would be much cheaper to populate it yourself.

Now looking at your post I'd say you don't have too much experience so you will most likely need several iterations until you get the board right.

Do you really need your own board? Why not something off-the-shelf?
Do you really need a professionally made PCB?
Will it ever pay off?
There are enough methods to make your own prototype PCBs on the cheap.

I think you should discuss your design and manufacturing plans with someone who has experience. Reach out to the EEVBlog forums and provide more information than you did here.

Comment: Thanks Piglet, i have created few Arduino projects. But as i am integrating many components it is getting very difficult. My plan it to create a   small arduino like pcb with all the components i need do my proof of concept product. I am very new to the world of electronics so hitting many walls right now.

Comment: @Rahul you can get breakout-boards for pretty much any package if they don't fit into a breadboard anyway so often it's not cost-effective to have pcb manufactured for simple prototyping. but you can definitely safe a lot of money if you populate the board yourself as setup time of all the pick an place equipment only pays of in mass production. it's super expensive for a few or even a single board.